# React native FlatList ListHeaderComponent refresh

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have ListHeaderComponent inside FlatList and after I change the state my ListHeaderComponent is not changing. 
This is my header component

```
flatlistHeader = () =>
 {
   if (this.state.isRewarded) {
            return (
                <View>
                    <Text style={{ color: '#fff' }}>Is rewarded</Text>
                </View>
            );
        }
        else {
            return (
                <View>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress={() => this.showRewareded()}
                    >
                        <Text style={{ color: '#fff' }}>Reward me</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            )
        }
  }
```

As you can see I want to change the state after I see a rewarded video.
Why ListHeaderComponent is not updating?
Thank you!

Edit: FlatList component

```
                    <FlatList
                    horizontal
                    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                    data={this.state.data}
                    keyExtractor={(x, i) => i.toString()}
                    onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
                    initialNumToRender={7}
                    maxToRenderPerBatch={10}
                    removeClippedSubviews={true}
                    ListHeaderComponent={this.flatlistHeader}
                    renderItem={({ item }) =>
                        <View style={styles.container}>
                            <TouchableOpacity
                                activeOpacity={1}
                                onPress={() => this.changeBackground(item.bg)}
                                style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0 }}
                            >
                                <Image
                                    resizeMode='contain'
                                    source={{ uri: `${item.bg}` }}
                                    style={{ borderRadius: 6, position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0 }}
                                />
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                    }
                />
```

Comment: Can you please post the code of your FlatList component?

Comment: Sure. Edited the post.

Comment: please show the codes of changeBackground function.

Comment: @paulv try to past the prop `extraData={this.state.data}` to FlatList. It would be rerender the flatlist if the state.data changes. let me know if it worked